# Close a file on a network mapped drive

Tags: windows-7, mapped-drive

We have some shared folders that we use at work to transfer and edit files.

This is a network mapped drive, not an actual shared folder where we put files in.

Sometimes people forget to close the files they were using so we are stuck waiting for them to close them, it can take hours before they are back in their desk.

Is there a way to close a file that is opened in another computer?

I tried this:
[Remotely close open shared files](https://superuser.com/questions/643916/remotely-close-open-shared-files)
but it applies to shared files not mapped drives.

Comment: What type of files?

Comment: Using elevated PowerShell you may be able to close such files using `Close-SmbOpenFile`. See [this article](https://sid-500.com/2017/09/11/powershell-find-open-files-smb-share/) and test if it works for you. However, forcefully closing files may lose unsaved work.

Comment: @Dave Excel files mostly.

Comment: @harrymc Unsaved work isn't an issue as it is automatically saved every few minutes. I will give it a try

Comment: @harrymc According to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/8d20a43d-f9f3-4c06-a2c0-e498cff0892c/getsmbconnection-is-not-recognized-name-of-cmdlet?forum=ITCG). `XXXX-SmbOpenFile` is available from Windows 8.1 and later versions

Comment: There are equivalents on Windows 7, but they must be run on the server where the share is defined.